# How can i send emails without a server ? Only front-end Javascript with sendgrid or

Tags: javascript, email, frontend, sendgrid, web-frontend

i was wondering lately how i could send emails with only a front-end language like Javascript through Email as a Service apps like sendgrid or mandrill or so.

Sendgrid and mandrill have Curl APIS, so basically i can just do an AJAX post request to their API to send a mail but the thing is, i will have to put my API secret key in the JS file, this means it will be public... while it's supposed to be secret.

On those two apps, there's nothing in the docs concerning front-end use except having your own server which will use the API, but i'm currently on front-end based project. No server programming, the server only renders the assets that's all.

Do you guys know any method or apps of this kind to acheive this ? Thanks

Comment: For as far as I know is this impossible without showing a secret key.

Comment: mmmh but doing this with a secret key sets some security problems because anybody could use my key, won't they ? @RobinR

Comment: That's what I said. It is possible? But when you'll do it without PHP or something else of unreadable client files, it'll be an security issue.

Comment: well i found this : http://www.emailjs.com it seems they found a way i guess @RobinR

Comment: if you also setup automated emails using a different type of third party solution - http://ifttt.com can email you if you use the new Maker channel to  monitor a website, it works from a regular POST command. It won't be superreliable but should let you know id there is a problem

Comment: the mailto using the end user's client (if they have one)  is also possible.

Comment: @Mousey the mailto is not automatic and can't send html emails, but thanks for the ifttt i'll check this out

Answer (score 17):

You can use FormSpree. Just provide the url in form action.

https://formspree.io/

Comment: Nah, "By default, a user is shown a Formspree "Thank You" page after submission." Have to pay to have a custom form submission page and you're limited to 50 emails/month on the free plan.

Comment: Yeah, free tier for this service seems very limited. This is a fully backend based solution, but you pay someone to take care of this backend for you.

Answer (score 5):

Several suugestions

- [dropbox forms](http://lifehacker.com/5782180/dropbox-forms-is-the-easiest-way-to-let-anyone-send-a-file-to-your-dropbox-account) via jotbox includes [encryption and a paid SSL option](http://www.jotform.com/faq/)
- [sendgrid using parse cloud instructions](https://sendgrid.com/blog/send-email-static-websites-using-parse/)
- third party service, eg [123contactform](http://www.123contactform.com/email-form/)
- use a not-so-secure php form with extra javascript to mask the email address, see responses on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603363/good-form-security-no-captcha) including Dave Jarvis' php code

Comment: those are very good alternative solutions thanks ! but for 2 of them i will have to create remotely the form and embed it (which was not the initial idea) and for sendgrid and php, there is some backend code to do (which was not the idea too, but is a good alternative for me but for a front-end only dev not so good alternative), and the key problem is still there, it's public so stealable... but i guess it's like FB or common APIS where you can limit access of the key from a certain host only @mousey

Comment: @darkylmnx the last option involves writing your own code from scratch but leaves you needing to mask the email address and possibly use encryption and/or SSL. The **third party service** option lets you add extra fields and customise the form, you can build your own form around their suggestions. `OAuth` is an alternative to the API key too, which is what **dropbox forms/jot box** uses

Comment: Hi @darkylmnx have you found anything to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Smtp.js](https://www.smtpjs.com/) or [emailjs](https://www.emailjs.com/) for frontend.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a serverless architecture with AWS Lambda functions written in JavaScript.

Comment: well that would mean I'd need to code, which I didn't want, i'm looking for tools to do front-end-only development. Apparently Mailchimp has an api for that but there's still some backend code needed which is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep the key secure you can use something like Aerobatic's [HTTP Proxy](https://www.aerobatic.com/docs/http-proxy) to specify the key and proxy through the server environment.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to let each user use his or her own outgoing mail server, by using a mailto: link, which allows you to specify the header information and also a quasi-header named “body”, which puts the content you want into the message body.

Comment: I don't think if that would be the most optimal solution here. The user would be sending a mail to himself. That's not professional way of doing things.