# Submit Contact Responses To email

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, node.js

I am using `repl.it` to build my website, however, `repl.it` has a server named HTML/CSS/JS and it does not support PHP which is mainly used to submit contact responses to email. The website is built in the HTML/CSS/JS Server. So I cannot use PHP to submit contact responses to email. Is there an alternate way of doing it with Node.js?

I still have the PHP set up but it just needs to be converted to Node.js if that is possible.

### PHP File:

```
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['subject'];
if(empty($fname) || 
empty($lname) || 
empty($email_address) || 
empty($message)){
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}else{
//some other code 
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission:" . $name;
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: " . $name . "\n ".
"Email: $email_address\n Message \n " . $message;
$headers = "From:" . $myemail . "\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:" . $email_address;
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header('Location: thank-you.html');
}
```

### REST OF The CODE:

```css
input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: rgb(62, 3, 179);
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="contact.php" method="POST">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required>

            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>

            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Is there a way to translate the PHP code into Javascript, and whenever the user hits the submit button, the responses get sent to email?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do this, but we're not going to rewrite your code for you. Where, specifically do you need help?

Comment: Code is only part of the issue. In general you can't send mail directly  from unregistered domains. This question is far too broad as outlined in the [help] and will require you to do significant research on your own

Comment: You may wanna take a look at this [link](https://nodemailer.com/about/).

Comment: Could you please check it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: Hi , I found something for you maybe it will help you , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041229/how-can-i-send-emails-without-a-server-only-front-end-javascript-with-sendgrid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, although [`repl.it`](https://replit.com) has done a lot of progress since it has been online, like featuring [hosting your `repl`](https://replit.com/site/hosting) as well as theirs unique [`upm`](https://blog.replit.com/upm) (repl.it universal package manager), I'd suggest that it isn't, at least yet, a suitable platform to build such an app despite being inherently simple. `repl.it` is a very restricted platform and for good security-wise reasons.

With that being said, in case you insist on building this app in their environment while assuming you don't have any `node.js` background, instead of creating an `HTML,CSS,JS repl`, you could create a `PHP Web Server` one and upload all the website's static files in the local folder under the repl's `Files` section.

Now, as mentioned before, because `repl.it` is a very restricted environment you'd probably notice that it doesn't support the PHP's [`mail`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php) function, nor [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php). As a workaround, you can use an email sending API like [SendGrid's](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/email-api/) (btw they offer a [free tier plan](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/), allowing you to send 100 emails/day) and implement it using the [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function, which, apparently, `repl.it` does fully support.

An example would be something as follows:

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Get in Touch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="contact.php" method="POST">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required>

            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required>

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>

            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

### style.css

```
input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: rgb(62, 3, 179);
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

### scripts.js

```
(() => {
    //Serialize the form at index.html page and send a proper XmlHttpRequest to ./send-mail.php
})();
```

### index.php

```
<?php

  readfile('index.html');
  die();

?>
```

### send-mail.php

```
<?php

$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['subject'];

if(empty($fname) || 
empty($lname) || 
empty($email_address) || 
empty($message)){
  echo "All fields are required!";
}

else {

$mailOptions = array(
  'firstName' => $fname,
  'lastName' => $lname,
  'emailAddress' => $email_address,
  'subject' => "Contact form submission: $fname $lname",
  'body' => "You have received a new message. ".
            "Here are the details:\nName: $fname $lname\n".
            "Email: $email_address\nMessage:\n$message"
);

$result = sendMail($mailOptions);

//$result error handling, ensuring the email has been sent, etc.

}


function sendMail($mailOptions)
{
  $sendEndpoint = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send';

  //Acording to SendGrid's API email send request
  $payload = '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "website_owner@domain.tld"}]}],
  "from": {"email": "' . $mailOptions['emailAddress'] . '"},"subject": "' . $mailOptions['subject'] . '",
  "content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "' . $mailOptions['body'] . '"}]}';

  $opts = array('http' =>
      array(
          'method'  => 'POST',
          'header'  => array(
            'Authorization: Bearer <<YOUR_API_KEY>>',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
          ),
          'content' => $payload
      )
  );

  $context = stream_context_create($opts);

  return file_get_contents($sendEndpoint, false, $context);
}

?>
```

**This example is only a demonstration for you to get an idea regarding how to do so. Just bear in mind that it doesn't apply any security best practices whatsoever!**

Comment: Does the above code send it to email? What do I replace `<<YOUR_API_KEY>>` with? I am not sure where to find the API key

Comment: @CodeUser2300 As mentioned, assuming you send the `POST` request to `send-mail.php` endpoint properly using an `XmlHttpRequest` under the same origin in `scripts.js`, a request to SendGrid's API should be sent. Regarding `<<YOUR_API_KEY>>`, you'll have to [register to their service](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/email-api/) and replace it with your own one. Please refer to their [API Reference](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/how-to-use-the-sendgrid-v3-api/authentication) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install nodemailer. then

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
  to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```